# modify Excel 2019 formula selecting everything after a character, to make first letter of result in Capital

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Windows 10
EXCEL 2019

The formula below looks at the contents of cell H2 and returns the characters after a full stop.

Example
Before H2 contains "some data.orange"
After H2 contains "orange"

I would like the formula to return to make the first letter of its result as a capital like "Orange"

This is the original Formula
`=RIGHT(H2,LEN(H2)-SEARCH(".",H2))`

I have tried
`=RIGHT(H2,LEN(H2)-SEARCH(".",UPPER(H2)))`

and

`=RIGHT(H2,LEN(H2)-SEARCH(".",PROPER(H2)))`

I tried moving "UPPER" and "PROPER" to other positions in the formula but excel throws a "too many arguments" error.

I am stumped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for your required output:

[image]

---

```
=PROPER(RIGHT(H2,LEN(H2)-SEARCH(".",H2)))
```

---

Or, Using `REPLACE()` with `PROPER()`

```
=PROPER(REPLACE(H2,1,FIND(".",H2),))
```

---

Even in the first formula one can use `FIND()` instead of `SEARCH()`

```
=PROPER(RIGHT(H2,LEN(H2)-FIND(".",H2)))
```

---

Or, if it has to be only the first letter of output where the result can have many other delimited strings/words etc.

[image]

---

```
=UPPER(LEFT(RIGHT(H2,LEN(H2)-FIND(".",H2))))&RIGHT(H2,LEN(H2)-FIND(".",H2)-1)
```

---

Comment: Thank you, all of your suggestions work well. Is there any advantage to using FIND instead of SEARCH?

Comment: @Bel the only advantage is makes the formula bit shorter other than that there is nothing special also i used it because you are trying to find a character so there is no need to use `SEARCH()` if it was related to some words or strings then we could have used `SEARCH()` which is case insensitive while `FIND()` is case sensitive